# How to write a BroadcastReceiver that takes extra from pendingIntent.getActivity

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent, intentfilter

I have a notification that has an action button. IFF the action is clicked on, it will open up a specific view in my app and the notification will dismiss itself. I know for dismissing notification on notification click, I can simply setAutoCancel(true) and it will does the trick. However, since action is added by NotificationCompat.Builder().addAction, notification will not dismiss itself without a proper notificationManager.cancel(id), so I try to put extra in my intent to pass notification id, but now nothing is working correctly after that. Action now brings the app to foreground if minimize and does nothing if it's already in foreground (instead of my destination) and receiver doesn't seem to have receieved anything.

Heres my code in NotificationPublisher.kt

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
                    //a uri to destination fragment
                    data = intents.getDestination()
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

                }
                intent.putExtra("notification_id", idHashCode)
                val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,idHashCode,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
return NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNEL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(subTitle)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVibrate(LongArray(2) { 1000 })
            .setNumber(1)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(0,getActionTextWithColor(context, R.string.go_to_destination, R.color.primary), pendingIntent)
```

NotificationReceiver.kt

```
class NotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val id = intent.getIntExtra("notification_id", -1)
        if(id > 0){

            val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager.cancel(id)
        }
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.myApp.notification.NotificationReceiver"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <data
                    android:host="myApp.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/destination"
                    android:scheme="myApp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Any thoughts on how I can make this work? Or if this doesn't make sense (I'm not very experience in Android), is there another approach I can try?

I tried puting extra in NotificationCompat.Builder but that also doesn't work
Maybe I can call manger.cancelAll() to get rid of all notification but that seems like a very desperate attempt and I feel like there has to be a smart/correct way of doing this

Comment: With this code, the `BroadcastReceiver` will never be called. Edit the question and show the rest of the manifest. It isn't clear what you are trying to do here with the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 0):

`PendingIntent.getActivity` will set up to use `startActivity()` to pass the enclosed `Intent`.

If you really want to go to the `BroadcastReceiver`, you need to use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

If instead, you really want to go bring the `Activity` to foreground, you should register the `<intent-filter>` on the `Activity`. You can then get the data from the `Intent` by looking at the `intent` property in `Activity.onCreate()`.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Does my intent-filter here make sense though? I have a suspicion that I might not understand how that work as well

Comment: And also, I don't understand why the action doesn't perform correctly if I putExtra in it, I might have overread it on the documentation, but I didn't see anywhere saying that an ACTION_VIEW intent cannot contain extras. Or could this possibly be something else that's going wrong in my code?

Comment: Intent matching can be fun to get right, but the extras shouldn't affect the intent matching.

The first issue is that the intent filter can't match because you're using PendingIntent.getActivity. Assuming your URI is myApp://myApp.com/destination* it should match if you change to PendingIntent.getBroadcast (or move the intent filter to the activity in the manifest)

What does intents.getDestination() return?

Oh - and you're creating an implicit intent - you need to add CATEGORY_DEFAULT to the intent filter as well.